# Properties of resulting model selected by stepwise predictor removal

Tags: feature-selection, model-selection, model

Several authors (I mostly remember Vehetari and Faraway on this issue) bang on the fact that using p-value for model selection does not lead to a 'best model' or to a model with best predictive accuracy on new data.

My question is this: do we know what properties such a model does have (for example, that we know such a model underfits the data or whatever)? Does it have any known properties?